# Test JSON response of a POST Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, rspec

I am developing an exercise in Rails. I just have to create some users and let them login. When a user is created, I need to send a json respond (I know how to do that), but I don't know how to test using RSPEC that that response is correct. This is my attempt:

```
describe "with correct input" do
    before { @user.save }
    specify { expect(User.count).to eq(1) }

    it "should respond json" do
      post '/signup.json', :user => {:name => 'ppppp', :login => '1234567890'}
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(json["user_name"]).to eq('ppppp')
      expect(json["login_count"]).to eq('1234567890')
    end
end
```

When I try this I obtain the error: NoMethodError:undefined method `post'

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a controller spec? If yes, is the spec file placed under `spec/controllers` folder.

By default Rspec assumes the controller specs to be under this folder. If the file isn't in the controllers folder add `:type => :controller` to the example group.

Refer the Rspec [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It's in the spec/models folder.How can I add :type => :controller? I don't know where I must write it. Thank you again!

Comment: Try adding it to the describe method, if it doesn't work please Google it.